Z - filter - RSolve vs InverseZTransform for unit state response : RSolve gives an incorrect result, where is my mistake?
I want to compare the unit step response of a z-filter given by two different methods:

InverseZtransform,
RSolve.

InverseZTransform gives a correct result, while RSolve gives a wrong result.  Why is this? Where did I go wrong?
For the record, I've also calculated the result with ReccurenceTable (that I haven't shown here), which is also wrong.
The tested z transfer function is as follows (general second-order filter):
H (z) = (a0 + a1 z^-1 + a2 z^-2)/(b0 + b1z^-1 + b2 z^-2)

The corresponding recurrence equation is the following one (I'll skip over the details):
y(n) = a0*x(n)+a1*x(n-1)+a2*x(n-2)-b0*y(n)-b1*y(n-1)-b2*y(n-2)

Here's my code:
Clear["Global`*"];

a0 = 1; a1 = 2; a2 = 1;
b0 = 1; b1 = -1.8; b2 = 0.81;

sol = RSolve[
{
   x[n] == x[n - 1], 
   y[n] == a0 x[n] + a1 x[n - 1] + a2 x[n - 2] - b0 y[n] - b1 y[n - 1] - b2 y[n - 2], 
   x[0] == 1, x[1] == 1, y[0] == 0, y[1] == 0
}, 
{x[n], y[n]}, n]

DiscretePlot[{Re[sol[[1]][[2]][[2]]]}, {n, 0, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> Full,
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> Style[Framed[RSolve Result - Wrong], 16, Red, 
  Background -> Lighter[Black]]]

InverseZTransform[((a2 z^-2 + a1 z^-1 + a0)/(b2 z^-2 + b1 z^-1 + b0)) 
  ZTransform[UnitStep[k], k, z], z, k]

ListPlot[Table[%, {k, 0, 100}], 
  Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All, 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> Style[Framed[RSolve InverseZTransform Result - Good], 16, Green, 
  Background -> Lighter[Black]]]

Below is the code written in SCILAB obtained using a classic FOR/END loop.
clear x;
clear y;
a0 = 1;a1 = 2;a2 = 1;b0 = 1;b1 = -1.8;b2 = 0.81;
N = 100 ;
// Init conditions
x = ones(N,1);// 
y = zeros(N,1);
for n = 3:N
  y(n) = a0*x(n)+a1*x(n-1)+a2*x(n-2)-b0*y(n)-b1*y(n-1)-b2*y(n-2);
end
clf();
plot(y)
xgrid();
title("Unit step response for z filter from recurrence equation");
xlabel('n')
ylabel('y')

And the corresponding curve plot which corresponds exactly to that of Mathematica's InverseZTransform


As I don't have an answer, I'll rephrase my question as follows:
How can I transpose the following SCILAB/MATLAB code into MATHEMATICA?
clear x;
clear y;
a0 = 1;a1 = 2;a2 = 1;b0 = 1;b1 = -1.8;b2 = 0.81;
N = 100 ;
// Init conditions
x = ones(N,1);// 
y = zeros(N,1);
for n = 3:N
  y(n) = a0*x(n)+a1*x(n-1)+a2*x(n-2)-b0*y(n)-b1*y(n-1)-b2*y(n-2);
end
clf();
plot(y)
xgrid();
title("Unit step response for z filter from recurrence equation");
xlabel('n')
ylabel('y')

I'm interested in any solution, including the old-fashioned one with Do or For. As a reminder, my personal attempts with RSolve and RecurrenceTable give results that do not conform to those obtained with other calculation software. I must certainly have made mistakes that I can't identify.
Thanks in advance for your ideas.

This question and the linked question (also from OP) are essntially the same problem: y(n) = a0*x(n)+a1*x(n-1)+a2*x(n-2)-b0*y(n)-b1*y(n-1)-b2*y(n-2); has y(n) in both sides i.e. it's not an equation.

Yes you are right. There is a mistake in the recurrence equation. The good one is the following one : y(n)=(a0/b0)*x(n)+(a1/b0)*x(n-1)+(a2/b0)*x(n-2)-(b1/b0)*y(n-1)-(b2/b0)*y(n-2).

I am not familiar with SCILAB, but here is one take on modeling this transfer function in Mathematica, by both a transfer function model and a recurrence relation. I substituted values early in the derivation to reduce clutter.
(*define transfer function*)

values = {a0 -> 1, a1 -> 2, a2 -> 1, b0 -> 1, b1 -> -1.8, b2 -> 0.81};

(*use values immediately for simplicity*)
hz = (a0 + a1 z^-1 + a2 z^-2)/(b0 + b1 z^-1 + b2 z^-2) /. values // 
   Simplify;

(* step response output by transfer function*)
tfz = TransferFunctionModel[hz, z, SamplingPeriod -> 1];
outtfz = OutputResponse[tfz, Table[1, {100}]][[1]];

(*output described by numerator must depend only on input and state \
variables*)

num = Numerator[hz]

den = Denominator[hz]

{q, r} = PolynomialQuotientRemainder[num, den, z]

(*this shows two parallel paths to output*)
(*the input with gain 1 sums with a z-domain function*)
q + r/Expand[den]

(* 1+(0.19+3.8 z)/(0.8-1.8 z+z^2) *)

(* delay equations from delay diagram not drawn here*)
(* note that the denominator defines the state transition and the \
numerator describes the output *)
eqs = {
   y[n + 1] == 1.8 y[n] - .81 y[n - 1] + x[n],
   x[n + 1] == x[n],
   y[1] == 0,
   y[0] == 0,
   x[0] == 1,
   out[n] == x[n] + 3.8 y[n] + 0.19 y[n - 1]
   };

sol = RSolve[eqs, {y[n], x[n], out[n]}, n][[1]];

(*output from recurrence relation*)
output[n_] = out[n] /. sol;

outrec = Table[output[n] /. sol // Chop, {n, 100}];

(*compare results*)

ListPlot[{outtfz, outrec}, PlotLabel -> "Step Response", 
 PlotMarkers -> {"OpenMarkers", Small}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[{"From Transfer Function", "From Recurrence Relation"}, 
   Center]]

ListPlot[outrec - outtfz, PlotLabel -> "Error"]


Addendum in response to question on impulse response:
The step response in the z-domain was an input of repeated samples of value 1. The impulse response is a single sample of value one followed by repeated samples of value zero. Since transfer functions assume initial conditions of zero, this is a unit impulse. I also convert the discrete time model to continuous time and calculate the response to DiracDelta. This could be repeated in the recursion relation with appropriate values for the input x[n], but the control theory tools are so good there is little need.
Addendum
(*position for plot legends*)
pos = {Right, Center};

(*discrete time impulse is a unit single sample*)
impulseTrain = Prepend[Table[0, {99}], 1];

(*calculate response and plot it*)
discPlot = 
  ListPlot[impulseResponse = OutputResponse[tfz, impulseTrain], 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Discrete Time (z-domain)"}, pos]];

(*convert the discrete time model to continuous time*)
tfs = ToContinuousTimeModel[tfz, s];

(*response to delta function at t=1*)
continuousImplulseResponse = 
  OutputResponse[tfs, DiracDelta[t - 1], {t, 0, 100}];

(*plot it*)
contPlot = 
  Plot[continuousImplulseResponse, {t, 1, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Continuous Time (s-domain)"}, pos]];

(*show both plots*)
Show[contPlot, discPlot, PlotLabel -> "Impulse Response"]



Many thanks David, for your brilliant solution.

You’re very welcome, Pascal.

Hello David, now, after solving the case of the unit step response, I am trying to solve the case for the Impulse Response. No problem withOutputResponse (it is working well with DiscretDelta or KroneckerDelta), but how do you implement it with the second part of your code? Thank you in advance for your answer.
...
outfz = OutputResponse[tfz, 
   DiscreteDelta[n], {n, 0, 
    100}]; (* It also work with KroneckerDelta *)

ListPlot[outfz]
...


Hi Pascal, In discrete time the unit impulse is a single sample of unit strength. I have added an illustration of this to my answer above.

Thank you very much David

Hello David, I have replaced DiracDelta[t-1] by 2 Sin[t] Exp[-t] . I get the same answer. The curve overlaps perfectly with the other two. I can't prove that it's not a coincidence. Do you have any ideas?

It's not coincidence. You have constructed an approximation to a delta function which for the frequency response of this filter is close enough to make a very similar, but not exact, response. If you plot it you will see that it has a very delta-like plot in the first few seconds, and within 3 seconds its integral has reached 1.

OK, fine. The error is big from t = 1s to 4s.

Bill gave me this relevant solution, which works like a charm, following another question from me on the same subject. It's a replica of the MATLAB code.
a0 = 1; a1 = 2; a2 = 1; b0 = 1; b1 = -1.8; b2 = 0.81;
capN = 100; (*N is a predefined MMA function so use capN instead*)
x = Table[1, {capN}];
y = Table[0, {capN}];
For[n = 3, n <= capN, n++, 
 y[[n]] = 
  a0*x[[n]] + a1*x[[n - 1]] + a2*x[[n - 2]] - b0*y[[n]] - 
   b1*y[[n - 1]] - b2*y[[n - 2]]]
ListPlot[y]  (*Optionally use ListPlot[y,Joined->True] instead*)

